# How to save view position in sharedPrefs..?

Tags: java, android, position, sharedpreferences, ontouch

I wanna to move view on screen at any position on touch. I write some code and view is moving but i cant save position in sharedPrefs on save button. so please help me to save position of view which i use in other activity.

**I use my custom created SharedPref file which i use in All Saving Values.**

```
savebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPref.setValue(EditView.this,"View_X",dX);
            SharedPref.setValue(EditView.this,"View_Y",dY);
        }
    });

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            dX = view.getX() - event.getRawX();
            dY = view.getY() - event.getRawY();
            lastAction = MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            view.setY(event.getRawY() + dY);
            view.setX(event.getRawX() + dX);
            lastAction = MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if (lastAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                Toast.makeText(EditWatermark.this, "Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        default:
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Other Activity**

```
View view;
float savedX, savedY;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit);

    view = findViewById(R.id.View);
    savedX = SharedPref.getFloat(this,"View_X");
    savedY = SharedPref.getFloat(this,"View_Y");
    view.setX(savedX);
    view.setY(savedY);

}
```

In this Condition when move view and save value... and then go to other activity and check view position.. then i got that view is invisible.

.....Sorry for My Bad English....

Comment: Hi Akash, can you post the code where you try to save the data please?

Comment: @Slipoch question is update now u can try..

Answer (score 0):

Have two floats `X` and `Y` and save them on `ACTION_UP`:

```
//member variables of your class
private float X;
private float Y;


    .............
    .............
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        if (lastAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            Toast.makeText(EditWatermark.this, "Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }else{
        //store the values
        X = view.getX();
        Y = view.getY();
        }
        break;
        ............
        ............
```

Now on Button save click:

```
save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(View view){

//save values to preferences

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("view", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putFloat("state_x", X);
editor.putFloat("state_y", Y);
editor.apply();

}

});
```

When you want to query the values saved again:

```
//somewhere in your code where you want to query the last saved X and Y 

//get the last stored values
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("view", MODE_PRIVATE);
float savedX = pref.getFloat("state_x",0); //0 is default if nothing exist
float savedY = pref.getFloat("state_y",0); //0 is default if nothing exist

//set them back to the view
view.setX(savedX);
view.setY(savedY):
```

Comment: Thanks for answer me.. but i still confused about this.. i update question with my full condition.. can u solve it now

Comment: What is so confusing, just follow the steps.

Comment: i followed steps u can see in question.. but view is invisible when i open in other activity

Comment: I saw your question, you didn't use the stuff that I told you exactly.

Comment: you are saving dx and dy, something that has nothing to do with my answer, please follow exactly the answer.

Comment: thanks its solved.. but i got issue onCreate.. When i get from sharedPrefs and set in onCreate the position is changed.. but when i set position on button click listener... the position is perfect as like previous. can you solve it ??

Comment: If that helped accept the answer so others  with same problem would know that the answer is useful. You have to make sure that you are not setting the X and Y again somewhere in your code.If you have other problems I suggest you ask a new question and make it clear on where the new problem is.